# Title bar in android app is still apperaring

Tags: android, android-layout, eclipse-adt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="sditm.app"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >

    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".SditmActivity" 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="page1"></activity>
    <activity android:name="aboutActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="admissionActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="extraActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="mapsActivity"></activity>        
    <activity android:name="facultyloginActivity"></activity>
    <activity android:name="retriveActivity"></activity>
</application>
```

Thats my code of androidmanifest.xml  here i have entered the `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` 
but still when i run the app, it is shown.

Can anyone tell me how to get rid of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The theme attribute you passed `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` will remove title from only `SditmActivity` Activity if you want to remove your title bar from all the activity in your application put `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` with application tag

```
<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option is change Theme.base style. Open res/values/styles.xml and copy this:

```
<style name="Theme.Base" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

then put

```
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Base"
```

to aplication in androidmanifest.xml working on minSdkVersion < 11

Answer (score 0):

It took me a while to realize that the individual `activity` tags with the `AndroidManifest` had their own themes that needed to be either replaced or removed, which the actual answer above led me to realize, b/c I was already doing everything else.